# Create a multi level cli using click python module

Tags: python, python-click

I'm using click to build a command line interface for my python code.

The command is now becoming too complex and I'd like to split it into sub-commands. The interface I'm trying to obtain is something like:

```
mytool subcommand1 --option1 --option2
mytool subcommand2 arg1 --option1
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Make a `group` out of an entry function `cli`:

```py
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass    

@cli.group()
def subcommand1():
    #your code

@cli.group()
def subcommand2():
    #your code
```

Note it is important to use the decorator `@cli.group()` before the subcommands.